# SQL Query to count unique service and group by name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am fairly new to SQL and I am stuck on a query. I have the following table called `Appointment`

```
NAME    SERVICE DATE
-----------------------------    
John    Abc 2012-11-10
Michael Xyz 2012-11-10
Denis   Xyz 2012-11-10
Denis   Pqr 2012-11-06
John    Abc 2012-11-06
Michael Abc 2012-11-05
Sofy    Abc 2012-11-04
John    Pqr 2012-11-01
Michael Pqr 2012-11-01
Michael Abc 2012-10-21
John    Abc 2012-10-23
John    HFD 2012-10-23
John    BHU 2012-11-09
Michael KSD 2012-11-08
```

What I want to do is count the services for individuals between the dates `2012-11-01` and `2012-11-10`.

Following is the required output

```
NAME    Abc Pqr Xyz
--------------------------------    
John    2   1   0
Michael 1   1   1
Denis   0   1   1
Sofy    1   0   0
```

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT  Name, COUNT(Distinct Service) 
FROM    [Appointment] 
WHERE   [DATE] between '2012-11-01 00:00:00.000' and '2012-11-10 23:59:59.999' 
AND     (Service = 'Abc' or Service = 'Pqr' or Service = 'Xyz') 
GROUP BY Name
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the query you have tried? This will help with any explanations of where you are going wrong.

Comment: @Ren : Select Name,count(Distinct Service)
from [Appointment] 
where [DATE] between '2012-11-01 00:00:00.000' and '2012-11-10 23:59:59.999'
and (Service = 'Abc' or Service = 'Pqr' or Service = 'Xyz')
group by Name

Comment: @KaustubhLohiya: Next time edit your question instead of commenting it. Btw, you should also tag the rdbms(f.e. MySql).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok , Thanks a ton . will do that

Comment: I am guessing you are using SQL Server. Modified the tags accordingly. (BTW, best to avoid using reserved words like `DATE` as column names when possible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Service = 'Abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Abc,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Service = 'Pqr' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Pqr,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Service = 'Xyz' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Xyz
FROM   TableName
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN CAST('2012-11-01' AS DATE) AND 
                     CAST('2012-11-10' AS DATE)
GROUP BY Name
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1d9b/25)

or

```
SELECT Name, Abc, Pqr, Xyz
FROM 
  (
      SELECT [Name], [Service]
      FROM TableName
      WHERE [Date] BETWEEN CAST('2012-11-01' AS DATE) AND 
                           CAST('2012-11-10' AS DATE)
  ) p
  PIVOT
  (
      COUNT ([service])
      FOR [Service] IN ( [Abc], [Pqr], [Xyz] )
  ) AS s
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1d9b/35)